# im trying to add images and media to my pages but the browse button and upload are missing

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin, media-images

i have more than 5000 products in my magento shop, since a week, all newls uploaded products dont have an image because of the missing browse and upload button. As well, under pages im trying to insert media and same problem.I have Magento ver. 1.9.0.1, Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m and adobe flash player is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my installation and I found the following link solved the problem.

> https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

You can always double check to make sure Chrome's Flash plugin is enabled

Comment: dear  my Chrome's Flash plugin is enabled. Your article is tested with  Magento Community Edition 1.7
Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.0 but My Magento version is Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Also check that the media folder is present in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media` as well as `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media`

Comment: //<![CDATA[
var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = 10485760000;
var maxUploadFileSize = '10000M';
id_f7ac6696960e9245aca64b7708419a2f_UploaderJsObject = new Flex.Uploader('id_f7ac6696960e9245aca64b7708419a2f_Uploader', 'http://www.khouryhome.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf', {"url":"http:\/\/www.khouryhome.com\/index.php\/KHAdmin\/catalog_product_gallery\/upload\/key\/de6ed7ae419751d7b96a8d2af729e719\/?SID=0dulfdfj753jnjvtggfkomun64","params":

Comment: Dear @JPK
please take note both folders exist in my CPANEL and no, i dont have any console errors.

Comment: Have performed any patch updates or installed any modules recently? You can try disabling external modules to see if that fixes the issues. If it does, there must be a conflict

Comment: actually, i have many updates but didnt apply them since i read on magento.com community that isnt effect and well performant.Community Edition 1.9.3 and SUPEE-8788 Provide Critical Security & Functional Updates – 10/12/2016 and this one :Updated Catalog Search Refinement extension - Download Now! from OCTOBER 2016; shall i apply them you think ?

Comment: keep in mind, that these button were appearing just fine before; its been around one week i am missing them on my backend.

Comment: I would apply the updates to see if that resolves the problem. Remember to take a full backup of your site and DB so you can revert should anything go wrong. Let me know if the issue still persits

Comment: ok i will. thank you JPK for the great help!!